# How to change panorama background programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

**Background of the panorama should change depending on `FlowDirection` of the current language.**

So I thought I should do this programmatically (is it possible in the XAML?)

I added this to the `OnNavigatedTo` event handler of the page:

```
ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
if (AppResources.ResourceFlowDirection == "RightToLeft")
{
   ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/CustomBackgroundMirror.png"));
   PanoramaRoot.Background = ib;
}
else
{
   ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/CustomBackground.png"));
   PanoramaRoot.Background = ib;
}
```

but after running, there is no image on the background, it is black.

I have a doubt that I am referring to the image badly.

**How can I solve this problem?**
or if the way is right, how can I get sure that the brush has an image?

**Update:** I have tested this too, but no difference:

```
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/CustomBackground.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Your updated code works for me. Just make sure the `Build Action` property of the image is set to `Content`

Comment: thanks @anderZubi. worked.. what a problem!

Comment: if you want add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your updated code,

```
ib.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/CustomBackground.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

works properly.

You just have to make sure that the `Build Action` property of the image is set to `Content`.